# Dynamics CRM Unable to Uninstall Managed Solution

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013

I've currently got an issue in our Dynamics CRM test environment, we currently cannot 'uninstall' the managed solution we have imported from our development environment.

The error we are getting when we try to uninstall is: "[entity] doesn't have a valid quick find query defined for it.". The log that they allow you to download with 'more details' essentially says the same thing with an error code of -2147089917.

I can't find any information on google or in the dynamics documentation around what could cause this issue or what it means.

We have done some basic customisation to the quick find query for that entity which appears to be in the solution. We can use the search and it uses the quick find query we have defined so that appears to be correct.

The solution we have is exported from our development environment and then imported as a managed solution to the test environment.

We've tried importing a newer version of the same solution over the top and we still can't delete.

Does anyone have any ideas as to what could cause/solve this issue.

Thanks,
Michael

Answer (score 0):

you have to remove the entities existing in the solution which you want to uninstall from the Quick find Search before deleting the solution.

To do this:

go to Settings > Administration > System Settings
In the tab marked “General” you will see a heading called “Set up Quick Find”
Select the record entities that you would like to remove and click OK

And now you should be able to uninstall your solution.

Hope this help!
Thinks,

Youssef.